# Glitches in getView

Tags: android, android-listview, contacts, adapter

I am showing the list of contacts .All good except that device has 1620 contacts so list is scrolling very slow and even sometimes get hangs.

Please help me out.

I tried using a check in getView method for `ConvertView!=null` but it alwayz inflate same view many times. thanks in advance..

My code for getView method:-

```
if(ConvertView==null)
        {   view= mInflater.inflate(R.layout.facebookfriend, null);
                TextView name=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                ImageView image=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            name.setText(mlist.get(position).get("name"));

                String Id=mlist.get(position).get("contactId");
                Log.e("Id",""+Id);
                CheckBox chkbox= (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
                chkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(
                            CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                        isSelected.set(position, isChecked);
                    }
                });

                                String photoid=mlist.get(position).get("photoId");
            Log.e("photoid",""+photoid);
                if(mlist.get(position).get("photoId")!=null){
                    Log.e("photoid",""+"photoid");
                    image.setImageBitmap(loadContactPhoto(Id, mlist.get(position).get("photoId")));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make the listview to load the data dynamically as per the requirement, see this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764441/use-android-dynamicaly-load-more-items-to-the-listview-need-help), also you should use [ViewHolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145602/how-to-implement-a-view-holder) to make it more efficient, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320478/how-to-load-the-listview-smoothly-in-android).

Comment: if (ConvertView == null) {
holder = new ViewHolder();
ConvertView= mInflater.inflate(R.layout.facebookfriend, null);
holder.name = (TextView)ConvertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

Comment: holder.imageView =ImageView)ConvertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
holder.chkbox= (CheckBox)ConvertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
ConvertView.setTag(holder);} else {    holder = (ViewHolder) ConvertView.getTag();}
holder.name.setText(mlist.get(position).get("Name").toString());
holder. chkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {@Override public void onCheckedChanged(

Comment: CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {isSelected.set(position, isChecked);
Log.e("position"+position,""+isChecked);
}
});
String Id=mlist.get(position).get("Contactid").toString();
Log.e("Id","--------------"+Id);
if(mlist.get(position).get("Photoid")!=null){
Log.e("photoid",""+"photoid");
holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(loadContactPhoto(Id, mlist.get(position).get("Photoid")));
}
}

Comment: Sorry i dun kn again how to write code that's y i put it in three comments
Please help !!

Comment: @Kabir121 pls post the code as another question, so that me and others can help you.

Comment: Hey abhinav thanks  Here is new link..
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10908866/glitches-in-adapters-getview-method)

Answer (score 1):

Use `ViewHolder pattern` for effecient `ListView`. Here is a detailed tutorial about this.
Try to implement this in you app and let us know if it helps.

[Efficient ListView’s in Android: View Holder Pattern](http://www.jmanzano.es/blog/?p=166&lang=en)