# Glitches in adapter's getView method

Tags: android, adapter, contacts

I am showing the list of contacts .All good except that device has 1620 contacts so list is scrolling very slow and even sometimes get hangs.

```
        I tried using a check in getView method for ConvertView!=null but it alwayz inflate same view many times. thanks in advance..

        My code for getView method:-
        if(ConvertView==null)
                {   view= mInflater.inflate(R.layout.facebookfriend, null);
                        TextView name=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                        ImageView image=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                    name.setText(mlist.get(position).get("name"));

                        String Id=mlist.get(position).get("contactId");
                        Log.e("Id",""+Id);
                        CheckBox chkbox= (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
                        chkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCheckedChanged(
                                    CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                                isSelected.set(position, isChecked);
                            }
                        });

                                        String photoid=mlist.get(position).get("photoId");
                    Log.e("photoid",""+photoid);
                        if(mlist.get(position).get("photoId")!=null){
                            Log.e("photoid",""+"photoid");
                            image.setImageBitmap(loadContactPhoto(Id, mlist.get(position).get("photoId")));
                    }
                }
            }
```

somebody told me to  make the listview to load the data dynamically as per the requirement,also to use ViewHolder to make it more efficient.
I have already tried it using view holder but it every time it inflates the single view again and again.My list is scrolling very smoothly but really do not know why it inflate the same view again and again. Please Help . 
    My code with viewHolder :-

```
                    if (ConvertView == null) {
                        holder = new ViewHolder();
                        ConvertView= mInflater.inflate(R.layout.facebookfriend, null);
                        holder.name = (TextView)ConvertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                        holder.imageView = (ImageView)ConvertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                        holder.chkbox= (CheckBox)ConvertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
                        ConvertView.setTag(holder);
                    } else {
                        holder = (ViewHolder) ConvertView.getTag();
                    }
                    holder.name.setText(mlist.get(position).get("Name").toString());

                    holder. chkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(
                                CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                            isSelected.set(position, isChecked);
                            Log.e("position"+position,""+isChecked);
                        }
                    });
                    String Id=mlist.get(position).get("Contactid").toString();

                    Log.e("Id","--------------"+Id);
                    if(mlist.get(position).get("Photoid")!=null){
                        Log.e("photoid",""+"photoid");
                        holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(loadContactPhoto(Id, mlist.get(position).get("Photoid")));
                        Log.e("position position",""+position);
                    }
                }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView name;
        ImageView imageView;
        CheckBox chkbox;
    }
```

My code for Imagefrom contact method,I am damn sure for this code

```
private Bitmap loadContactPhoto(String id, String photoId) {
        Long _id=Long.parseLong(id);
        Long _photoId=0l;
        if(photoId!=null){
            _photoId=Long.parseLong(photoId);
        }
        ContentResolver cr = Setting.this.getContentResolver();
        Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, _id);
        InputStream input = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(cr, uri);
        if (input != null) {
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        } else {
            Log.d("PHOTO", "first try failed to load photo");

        }

        byte[] photoBytes = null;
        Uri photoUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, _photoId);
        Cursor c = cr.query(photoUri,new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO },
                null, null, null);
        try {
            if (c.moveToFirst())
                photoBytes = c.getBlob(0);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            c.close();
        }

        if (photoBytes != null)
            return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(photoBytes, 0,
                    photoBytes.length);
        else
            Log.d("PHOTO", "second try also failed");
        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                R.drawable.default_image);
        return icon;
```

}

Comment: post your `loadContactPhoto()` method.

Comment: private Bitmap loadContactPhoto(String id, String photoId) {
  Long _id=Long.parseLong(id);
  Long _photoId=0l;
  if(photoId!=null){
   _photoId=Long.parseLong(photoId);
  }
  ContentResolver cr = Setting.this.getContentResolver();
  Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, _id);
  InputStream input = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(cr, uri);
  if (input != null) {
   return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
  } else {
   Log.d("PHOTO", "first try failed to load photo");

  }

Comment: byte[] photoBytes = null;
  Uri photoUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, _photoId);
  Cursor c = cr.query(photoUri,new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO },
    null, null, null);
  try {
   if (c.moveToFirst())
    photoBytes = c.getBlob(0);

  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } finally {
   c.close();
  }

Comment: if (photoBytes != null)
   return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(photoBytes, 0,
     photoBytes.length);
  else
   Log.d("PHOTO", "second try also failed");
  Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
    R.drawable.default_image);
  return icon;
I do not know how to send code in comment that's y i pasted in three segments Please Help

Comment: please edit your question & add these code with proper formatting. And the problem is here i think.

Comment: No i am damn sure this code is correct.Problem is in somewhere getview method , it is not getting position for particual view

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in `loadContactPhoto()` I think. Each time with `loadContactPhoto()` you are running query and get the Bitmap by decoding array. That's why the scrolling is getting slow.

Try to load all the contact images before loading the `ListView` and let us know what happened.

You can also follow this tutorial to load contact with photo using `SimpleCursorAdapter`.

[Add contact photo to your list application](http://www.droidnova.com/add-contact-photo-to-your-list-application,45.html)

Comment: Nopes when we scroll the getView method calls everytime and inflate the view for that i used ViewHolder . there is nothing to concern with that loadcontactimage method..

Comment: First try this way. How do you so sure about that loadContactImage working fine?

Comment: Beacuse my problem is not for slow scrolling , my problem is every time my single view inflates for every view...

Comment: I've checked one of my implemented List using ViewHolder. The number of items is over 50. and only 7 times inflating happens. Can you please post your full adapter code?

Comment: One more question. How do you know imflating happens every time

Comment: Dude it was my full adapter code rest all are overridden methods.. :)